# How can I VNC to a Mac which has booted from the Install DVD?

Tags: mac-osx, installation, vnc, screen-sharing

What steps do I follow to VNC into a Mac which has booted from the Install DVD?

Have heard you can't do this with the Leopard Install DVD anymore - if so, instructions for the Tiger Install DVD would be handy to know also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. boot your Mac from the Install DVD
2. open Screen Sharing and connect to the IP of your Mac (it's IP will supplied by DHCP, you might have to look it up on your router/DHCP server — or use "arp -a" to locate it)
3. for VNC login and password, leave the username blank, but type in the first 8 digits of your Mac's hardware serial number

I have tested this with the Leopard Server Install DVD, and it works fine.

Comment: Nice work. I could never remember the VNC login for OS X Server. It'd be neat if they include this in Snow Leopard Client since it does not work with Leopard Client.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible with the Leopard **Client** DVD without modification: ARDAgent is not available on the DVD installation. You can however make a NetBoot image or a custom image with ARDAgent installed (Put it in `/System/Library/CoreServices`) and it should launch the VNC server (have not tried it personally as I've used a NetInstall image and now only deploy images) automatically by running `echo -n enabled > /Library/Preferences/com.apple.ScreenSharing.launchd`, if not you'll have to run `kickstart` (eg. `sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -activate -privs all -setvnclegacy yes -setvncpw PASSWORD`)

Note: Tested on a 10.5.0 and a 10.5.6 retail disk. I assume it would be the same for a 10.5.4 disk as well.

The Leopard **Server** DVD however does allow remote installations that are controlled by VNC.

What about running a NetInstall image, doing a Remote Install (using Remote Install.app) or sending an image instead?

Comment: it's something I just want to know how to do for the cool factor ;-) and, darn it, Server Assistant just isn't cool enough

Comment: I agree it would be much cooler and make life easier for installations that don't warrant setting up NetBoot (or having a OS X Server around).